# Test Methods Using pytest

Tags: python, oop, testing, pytest

I am new here trying to learn python. I was working on a speech recognition project, and I need to write some test functions for my code I have used pytest before, with regular functions that returned something, but in this case I am really confused on how to test the methods, I already know how to import them to a test file but I am lost here on what and how to test it. I will really appreciate any type of guidance you can provide me. Thank you!

`

```
#Imported modules
import sys
import wave, contextlib, math, time
import speech_recognition as sr
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    """Main window GUI."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialisation function."""
        self.mp4_file_name = ""
        self.output_file = ""
        self.audio_file = "speech.wav"
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        """Define visual components and positions."""
        # Main window
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(653, 836)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 20, 161, 41))
        # Selected video file label
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.selected_video_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.selected_video_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 20, 371, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.selected_video_label.setFont(font)
        self.selected_video_label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.selected_video_label.setText("")
        self.selected_video_label.setObjectName("selected_video_label")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 90, 161, 41))
        # Transcribed text box
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.transcribed_text = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.transcribed_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 320, 381, 431))
        self.transcribed_text.setObjectName("transcribed_text")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 280, 161, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.transcribe_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.transcribe_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.transcribe_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 150, 221, 81))
        # Transcribe button
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.transcribe_button.setFont(font)
        self.transcribe_button.setObjectName("transcribe_button")
        self.transcribe_button.clicked.connect(self.process_and_transcribe_audio)
        # progeress bar
        self.progress_bar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progress_bar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 250, 381, 23))
        self.progress_bar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progress_bar.setObjectName("progress_bar")
        self.message_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.message_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 760, 651, 21))
        # Message label (for errors and warnings)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.message_label.setFont(font)
        self.message_label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.message_label.setText("")
        self.message_label.setObjectName("message_label")
        self.output_file_name = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.output_file_name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 90, 371, 41))
        # Output file name
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.output_file_name.setFont(font)
        self.output_file_name.setObjectName("output_file_name")
        # Menubar options
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 653, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuAbout = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuAbout.setObjectName("menuAbout")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen_mp4_video_recording = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_mp4_video_recording.setObjectName("actionOpen_mp4_video_recording")
        self.actionOpen_mp4_video_recording.triggered.connect(self.open_audio_file)
        self.actionAbout_vid2text = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAbout_vid2text.setObjectName("actionAbout_vid2text")
        self.actionAbout_vid2text.triggered.connect(self.show_about)
        self.actionNew = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNew.setObjectName("actionNew")
        self.actionNew.triggered.connect(self.new_project)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen_mp4_video_recording)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionNew)
        self.menuAbout.addAction(self.actionAbout_vid2text)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuAbout.menuAction())
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        """Translate UI method."""
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Selected video file:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Output file name:"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Transcribed text:"))
        self.transcribe_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Transcribe"))
        self.output_file_name.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "interview1.txt"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuAbout.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "About"))
        self.actionOpen_mp4_video_recording.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open mp4 video recording"))
        self.actionAbout_vid2text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "About video to speech"))
        self.actionNew.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New"))
    def open_audio_file(self):
        """Open the audio (*.mp4) file."""
        file_name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        if file_name[0][-3:] == "mp4":
            self.transcribe_button.setEnabled(True)
            self.mp4_file_name = file_name[0]
            self.message_label.setText("")
            self.selected_video_label.setText(file_name[0])
        else:
            self.message_label.setText("Please select an *.mp4 file")
    def convert_mp4_to_wav(self):
        """Convert the mp4 video file into an audio file."""
        self.message_label.setText("Converting mp4 to audio (*.wav)...")
        self.convert_thread = convertVideoToAudioThread(self.mp4_file_name, self.audio_file)
        self.convert_thread.finished.connect(self.finished_converting)
        self.convert_thread.start()
    def get_audio_duration(self, audio_file):
        """Determine the length of the audio file."""
        with contextlib.closing(wave.open(audio_file,'r')) as f:
            frames = f.getnframes()
            rate = f.getframerate()
            duration = frames / float(rate)
            return duration
    def transcribe_audio(self, audio_file):
        """Transcribe the audio file."""
        total_duration = self.get_audio_duration(audio_file) / 10
        total_duration = math.ceil(total_duration)
        self.td = total_duration
        if len(self.output_file_name.toPlainText()) > 0:
            self.output_file = self.output_file_name.toPlainText()
        else:
            self.output_file = "my_speech_file.txt"
        # Use thread to process in the background and avoid freezing the GUI
        self.thread = transcriptionThread(total_duration, audio_file, self.output_file)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.finished_transcribing)
        self.thread.change_value.connect(self.set_progress_value)
        self.thread.start()
    def finished_converting(self):
        """Reset message text when conversion is finished."""
        self.message_label.setText("Transcribing file...")
        self.transcribe_audio(self.audio_file)
    def finished_transcribing(self):
        """This run when transcription finished to tidy up UI."""
        self.progress_bar.setValue(100)
        self.transcribe_button.setEnabled(True)
        self.message_label.setText("")
        self.update_text_output()
    def set_progress_value(self, val):
        """Update progress bar value."""
        increment = int(math.floor(100*(float(val)/self.td)))
        self.progress_bar.setValue(increment)
    def process_and_transcribe_audio(self):
        """Process the audio into a textual transcription."""
        self.transcribe_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.message_label.setText("Converting mp4 to audio (*.wav)...")
        self.convert_mp4_to_wav()
    def update_text_output(self):
        """Update the text box with the transcribed file."""
        f = open(self.output_file, "r")
        self.transcribed_text.setText(f.read())
        f.close()
    def new_project(self):
        """Clear existing fields of data."""
        self.message_label.setText("")
        self.transcribed_text.setText("")
        self.selected_video_label.setText("")
        self.output_file_name.document().setPlainText("")
        self.progress_bar.setValue(0)
    def show_about(self):
        """Show about message box."""
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setWindowTitle("About video to Speech")
        msg.setText("Nelson Petro - CSE 111")
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msg.exec_()
class convertVideoToAudioThread(QThread):
    """Thread to convert mp4 video file to wav file."""
    def __init__(self, mp4_file_name, audio_file):
        """Initialization function."""
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.mp4_file_name = mp4_file_name
        self.audio_file = audio_file
    def __del__(self):
        """Destructor."""
        self.wait()
    def run(self):
        """Run video conversion task."""
        audio_clip = AudioFileClip(self.mp4_file_name)
        audio_clip.write_audiofile(self.audio_file)
class transcriptionThread(QThread):
    """Thread to transcribe file from audio to text."""
    change_value = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, total_duration, audio_file, output_file):
        """Initialization function."""
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.total_duration = total_duration
        self.audio_file = audio_file
        self.output_file = output_file
    def __del__(self):
        """Destructor."""
        self.wait()
    def run(self):
        """Run transcription, audio to text."""
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        for i in range(0, self.total_duration):
            try:
                with sr.AudioFile(self.audio_file) as source:
                    audio = r.record(source, offset=i*10, duration=10)
                    f = open(self.output_file, "a")
                    f.write(r.recognize_google(audio))
                    f.write(" ")
                self.change_value.emit(i)
            except:
                print("Unknown word detected...")
                continue
            f.close()
            
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I imported succesfully the methods but I am really lost on how to test them.

So far I did this to test when the user selected and file that is not *mp4 and the main window constructor

```
def test_MainWindowConstructor():
  ui = Ui_MainWindow()
  assert ui.mp4_file_name == ""
  assert ui.output_file == ""
  assert ui.audio_file == "speech.wav"

def test_that_providing_a_raw_file_is_rejected():
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
  ui = Ui_MainWindow()
  ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
  ui.actionOpen_mp4_video_recording.triggered
  QFileDialog.getOpenFileName = "video.raw"  
  ui.open_audio_file
  assert ui.message_label.text == "Please select an *.mp4 file"
```

Comment: Indeed, your code does not look very testable. What are you trying to test for ? Unit tests are not always a good solution.

Comment: Hello @Lenormju, thank you for replying, I am taking a course named "programming with functions" and we were asked to find a good project and write some test functions. I was able to write test functions for my previous personal projects, for my functions that returned something, but in this case, I am confused about how to test that the functions are working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tests need context, you test **for** something.
For example :

- if your program simply starts (smoke test),
- if a bug was fixed (regression test),
- if it satisfies a functional requirement (acceptance test),
- if it satisfies a non-functional requirement (performance, accessibility, ... test),
- ...

Unit tests (which is an overloaded term, there are many different definitions) to me are more about how to write the test (cut a unit from the rest) than what it tries to check.
So you can write unit tests for many reasons, only they are meant to target just a small part of the code (ideally just a class or function/method).

For example you could test for translation (pseudo-code) :

```py
def test_that_the_app_is_by_default_in_english():
    ... # start the app
    # `retranslateUi` gets implicitly called
    assert main_window.label_3.text == "Selected video file:"

def test_that_the_app_is_translated_in_spanish_when_the_user_locale_is_es_ES():
    ... # set the locale 
    ... # start the app
    # `retranslateUi` gets implicitly called
    assert main_window.label_3.text == "Archivo de vídeo seleccionado :"
```

Or for example you could test that the app rejects non-mp4 files :

```py
def test_that_providing_a_raw_file_is_rejected():
    ... # start the app
    ... # mock `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName` to return "video.raw"
    ... # simulate user triggering the "Open mp4 video recording" action
    # `open_audio_file` gets called, calls the mock, and handles the input
    assert main_window.message_label.text == "Please select an *.mp4 file"
```

Or you could test how a corrupted file gets handled.

Or you could test that an "about window" gets opened when the user clicks on the corresponding menuitem.

Or ...

There are many possibilities.

But you may figure a pattern : each time we create an instance, call methods on it, then check its fields (or possibly the return values of its methods).
That is because in Oriented-Object Programming, `self` is an input **and** output parameter of each method. So even if a method does not return anything (`None`), actually it returns a possibly modified `self`, which we can check on.
Other times, `self` may be unchanged but there have been **side-effects** : `print` to the terminal, file write, http request, ... These are changes outside of the system, and thus difficult to test. Unit tests **mock** them often, either to ignore them or to actually check them, depending of the test goal.

Your question is not particularly fit for StackOverflow, it is dedicated to clear-cut technical questions, while yours is vague open-ended. That is not to say it is not a good question per se, but that StackOverflow is not the place it should have been posted. But because I don't know where else, I partly answered anyway.

Hoping you get a sense of why your question is difficult to answer.

---

### Edit

As per your comment, I will provide an example of such a test.

But first, it would have been better to have a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) than your actual code, which is long and takes time to understand, requires to install many dependencies, ...

Here is something simpler to play with :

```py
import sys
import datetime
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None)  # because MainWindow

        self.setWindowTitle("Clock on demand")

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("", central_widget)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("What time is it ?", central_widget)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.update_time)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.update_time()

    def update_time(self):
        self.label.setText(datetime.datetime.now().time().isoformat())


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is a very simple application : one small window, two relevant widgets (a button and a label), it does only one thing.

Now suppose we want to test that clicking on the button updates the time.

```py
def test__when_user_clicks_then_the_time_is_updated():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    # no need to call `show`, we don't need to **see** it, it just needs to exist
    # DO NOT call `app.exec` because it is **blocking** !! (and because the window isn't shown you can't even close it manually)

    time_before = main_window.label.text()
    time.sleep(1)

    # instead, you will have to simulate a click
    from PyQt5 import QtTest, QtCore
    QtTest.QTest.mouseClick(main_window.button, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)

    time_after = main_window.label.text()

    assert time_before < time_after  # works on strings, except at midnight
```

This is a basic test : it reads the time, waits one second, click to update the time, reads again, and compare.

I can rewrite it this way if you prefer :

```py
from PyQt5 import QtTest, QtCore


def init_app() -> MainWindow:
    return MainWindow()


def left_mouse_click_on_button(widget: QtWidgets.QWidget) -> None:
    QtTest.QTest.mouseClick(widget, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)


def test__when_user_clicks_then_the_time_is_updated():
    # given
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # required
    main_window = init_app()
    time_before = main_window.label.text()

    # when
    time.sleep(1)  # waiting a bit
    left_mouse_click_on_button(main_window.button)

    # then
    time_after = main_window.label.text()
    assert time_before < time_after  # time got updated
```

Do you see how the test works ? I setup the app for testing (non-visible), I send stimulus (time passing, then a click), then I check for the result.

This is the basis of testing.
If you have other questions, you did not state them in your originaly. I hesitated to flag your question for lacking focus. StackOverflow is meant to answer precise questions. Yours wasn't.

> I mean how to start the app and perform the other steps ... # start the app ... # mock QFileDialog.getOpenFileName to return "video.raw" ... # simulate user triggering the "Open mp4 video recording" action

These are better questions ! You should search online for how to do it, and if you don't find a satisfying answer, you can come back with a precise question.

Comment: Hello Lenormju! Yeah, that is exactly what I am looking for. I was able to test the default values for the Ui_Mainwindow constructor if you can tell me how to code this function
def test_that_providing_a_raw_file_is_rejected(): that would be really helpful for me, I am new in OOP and it is really difficult for me to understand some concepts, but with one complete example I think I will be able to code the other test function, I am really grateful for your help, and I am so sorry for my question, it is just I did not know what to do.

Comment: I mean how to start the app and perform the other steps 
... # start the app
    ... # mock `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName` to return "video.raw"
    ... # simulate user triggering the "Open mp4 video recording" action
   I have been trying for hours today and reading how to do this but I have not been able to do it.

Comment: Hello @Lenormju! I am so sorry for bothering you again. I edited my question and added two test functions I did, the first passed, and the second did not. I am new at OOP, I would really appreciate any advise regarding my second test function. Thank you so mucho.

Comment: @NelsonPetro usually, editing your post to add more questions is not allowed, better create another post (referencing this one). You say the second test fails, but you don't give me the error message, so I have to guess. If it is `'str' object is not callable`, then it's because you replaced a function (`QFileDialog.getOpenFileName`) by a string (`"video.raw"`) so you can't call it. You should instead do `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName = my_function`. (which will fail because it should return a `tuple`, not just a string). Please consider creating a new question for the follow-up.

Comment: Hello @Lenormju! I am sorry. I think I need to read the rules and guidelines. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @NelsonPetro it is not just about the rules, but it is much easier to answer on a new question (and find new persons interested) than adding comments and editing a previous answer.